# LC-3 Assembly Calculator

Tags: calculator, lc3

What am I getting this output:

ENTER FIRST OPERAND : 4

ENTER SECOND OPERAND: 2

ADDITION: 6

SUBTRACTION: 2

MULTIPLICATION:

DIVISION:

----- Halting the processor -----

From this code:

```
    .ORIG x3000
;
; Program to add two numbers. Prompt user to enter the numbers.
; The numbers are ASCII characters. Convert them to integers by
; subtracting x30 from the ASCII code. Store the operands in
; registers R1 and R2.
; Add the two integers. Store the sum in R0. Convert the sum to
; an ASCII character by adding x30 to it. Otherwise, you will not
; be able to print it.
;

    ld R3, MINUSx30 ; R3 <- x-30 (ASCII 0)
    ld R6, PLUSx30

; GET THE FIRST OPERAND
    lea R0, getop1 ;Prompt user
    puts
    getc ; Read the character
    out ; Echo the character
    add R1, R0, R3 ; first operand is in R1

; GET THE SECOND OPERAND
    lea R0, getop2
    puts
    getc ; Read the next character
    out ; Echo the character
    add R2, R0, R3 ; second operand in R2

; OUTPUT A NEXT-LINE CHARACTER (10)
    and R0, R0, #0
    add R0, R0, #10 ;#10 is Line feed in ASCI
    out

; Output a Message
        LEA R0, ADD_RESULT
        PUTS

; ADD the two numbers, Convert result to ASCII & Display
    add R0, R1, R2 ; R0 <- R1 + R2
    ld R3, PLUSx30 ; R3 <- x30
    add R0, R0, R3 ; R0 <- R0 +x30
    out ; Output result

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ADDITION WORKS NO TOUCH

;Get twos compliment of second operand
        NOT R2, R2
    ADD R2, R2, #1
; Output a Message
        LEA R0, SUB_RESULT
        PUTS

; Perform subtraction by addition
    ADD R0,R1,R2    ; Perform operation
    BRZP POS        ; Result is positive 
    ADD R4, R0, #0  ; Result is negative. Save R0
    
; Result is negative, display ‘-‘ sign
        LEA R0, MINUS   ; Result negative. Display '-'
        PUTS
        ADD  R0, R4, #0 ; R0 <- R4
        NOT R0, R0      ; Take twos complement of result
        ADD R0, R0, #1
        POS LD R3, PLUS30
        ADD R0, R3, R0  ;Converts to ASCII digit
        OUT         ;Display Result

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; SUBTRACTION WORKS NO TOUCH
LEA R0, MUL_RESULT  ; Display multiplication result message
        PUTS
        AND R3, R3, #0      ; Clear R3
        LD R4, #0          ; Initialize R4 to 0 (accumulator)
MUL_LOOP ADD R3, R3, R1     ; Multiply R1 by R2
        ADD R4, R4, #1      ; Increment R4 (counter)
        ADD R2, R2, #-1     ; Decrement R2
        BRzp MUL_LOOP       ; Repeat until R2 is 0 or negative
        ADD R3, R3, R6  ; Convert result to ASCII
        OUT

        ; Division
        LEA R0, DIV_RESULT  ; Display division result message
        PUTS
        AND R3, R3, #0      ; Clear R3
        LD R4, #0          ; Initialize R4 to 0 (quotient)
DIV_LOOP ADD R3, R3, R2     ; Subtract R2 from R1
        BRN DIV_DONE        ; If result is negative, division is done
        ADD R4, R4, #1      ; Increment R4 (quotient)
        BRnzp DIV_LOOP      ; Repeat until result is negative
DIV_DONE ADD R4, R4, R6  ; Convert quotient to ASCII
        OUT
    HALT ; Done
; DATA DECLARATIONS

getop1      .STRINGZ "\nENTER FIRST OPERAND : "
getop2      .STRINGZ "\nENTER SECOND OPERAND: "
ADD_RESULT  .STRINGZ "\nADDITION: "
SUB_RESULT  .STRINGZ "\nSUBTRACTION: "
MUL_RESULT  .STRINGZ "\nMULTIPLICATION: "
DIV_RESULT  .STRINGZ "\nDIVISION: "

MINUSx30 .FILL x-30
PLUSx30 .FILL x30
PLUS30  .FILL x30
MINUS30     .FILL x-30 
MINUS       .FILL X2D 
.end ; END OF CODE
```

The addition and subtraction works fine together, but the the multiplication and division I get SQUARE ? marks as the answer. So please tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  What is the value in `R3`  —  the multiplication result, before adding `PLUSx30` (in `R6`) to it?  Why does it have that value?

Comment: R1 and R2 are supposed to hold your operands, but the multiply loop trashes R2, so the divide loop gets the wrong input.  And WHY do you have two copies each of 0x30 and -0x30?  Are you sure that OUT and PUTS do not damage any of the registers?

Comment: Also, `LD R4, #0` does not necessarily clear `R4`, but what you're counting (for multiplication) in `R4` doesn't make sense and is anyway not used.

Comment: There are several simple problems here, and if you cannot single step in the debugger, suggest you try to learn that.  On another note, try smaller inputs, like 2 & 2.

Comment: So how do I fix this issue? @ErikEidt

Comment: Did you try 2, 2 for inputs?  Using smaller inputs is one way to see what's going on.  Single step debugging is another.  Once you see what's going on, that's the first step to fixing it.

Comment: Yes, 

ENTER FIRST OPERAND : 2


ENTER SECOND OPERAND: 2

ADDITION: 4


SUBTRACTION: 0


MULTIPLICATION: 


DIVISION: 

Exiting

Comment: Learn to single step debug.  Using the debugger, you can ask yourself questions about the program, like what two numbers is it trying to add, trying to subtract, to multiply, and you can verify these as factual details rather than guessing or assuming.  That subtraction destroys one of the input values by negating it, so it is otherwise lost to the rest of the program.

Comment: i am using lc3tutor.org. There is no debugging option

Comment: sooo how do i fix it, or tell me what lines i need to fix